# Does every set "contain" the empty set?

Tags: set-theory

Define a property "$X$ contains $Y$" iff $Y \in X$ or $Z \in X$ and $Z$ contains $Y$ (meaning in a finite recursive sort of way). Then does every set contain $\emptyset$ (in ZFC maybe $\pm$ some axioms)? For example, every natural number (in any sensible constuction) contain $\emptyset$, and therefore every integer and rational does too. One could show that real numbers contain $\emptyset$, and therefore constructions based on the reals also. I think we probably need an axiom like $V=L$ but is that sufficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "containment relation" is equivalent to $Y\in\operatorname{tr cl}X$, where $\operatorname{tr cl} X$ is a [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure) of $X$. We can show that every transitive closure of a *non-empty* set has the empty set as its element.

*Proof*. We will use induction on [rank of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe#Definition). If $x$ is non-empty, then $\operatorname{rank} x\ge 1$.

If $\operatorname{rank} x=1$, so that $x\subseteq V_1=\{\varnothing\}$, then $x=\{\varnothing\}$. We can check that $\operatorname{tr cl}x\supseteq x$ for any $x$, so the transitive closure of $\{\varnothing\}$ contains the empty set.

Now assume that every $x\in V_\alpha$ (i.e. sets $x$ such that $\operatorname{rank} x<\alpha$) satisfies $\varnothing\in\operatorname{tr cl}x$. If $\operatorname{rank}x=\alpha$, then $x\subseteq V_\alpha$ so every elements of $x$ has rank $<\alpha$. Since
$\operatorname{tr cl} x\supseteq x\cup \bigcup x$ and $\varnothing\in \bigcup x$, $\varnothing \in \operatorname{tr cl}x$.

---

The proof uses the axiom of regularity: the consequence of the axiom of regularity is that the Von Neumann hierarchy covers the class of all sets.

Moreover, the axiom of regularity is necessary for the proof: it is consistent with ZF without regularity that a Quine atom (i.e., a set $x$ satisfying $x=\{x\}$) exists. We can see that the transitive closure of $x$ is just $x$, and $x$ does not contain the empty set.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the empty set doesn't.  But every nonempty set does.  To be precise, for any nonempty set $X$, there is a finite sequence $X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n$ with $X_0=\emptyset$, $X_n=X$, and $X_i\in X_{i+1}$ for each $i$.  This follows from the axiom of regularity (and is essentially a weak variant of it): if there existed a nonempty set $X$ which does not "contain" $\emptyset$ in this sense, then by regularity there would be an $\in$-minimal such set $X$.  But then since $X$ is nonempty, it has an element $Y$, and by $\in$-minimality of $X$, $Y$ contains $\emptyset$.  But then $X$ contains $\emptyset$ by appending one more term on the end of the sequence for $Y$.

(Note that there is a bit of sleight of hand in how I used regularity here, since regularity says only that a nonempty *set* has an $\in$-minimal element.  See the argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1564921/86856) for how to justify this usage.  (Or, as in Hanul Jeon's answer, you can use the cumulative hierarchy, but the same trick is needed to *prove* every set is in the cumulative hierarchy, so it amounts to the same thing.))